# Displaying results from database query in two columns

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to display results from a database in two columns but I can't seem to get it to work. I've seen some examples on here but they are very old and don't really follow what I'm doing. Below are the two errors I'm getting.All it outputs is the word "Array"

> Notice: Undefined offset: 99 in G:\xampp\htdocs\carDirectory\listing.php on line 19

> Notice: Array to string conversion in G:\xampp\htdocs\carDirectory\listing.php on line 23

```
    <?php
    include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
    include 'functions.php';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM roads ORDER BY roadName ASC";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt ->execute();
    //stmt ->store_result();
    //$stmt ->bind_result($roadID, $roadName, $reportingMark);
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    
    //$mid = $result->num_rows;
    $mid = ceil($result->num_rows/2);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {;
            $listing[] = $row;
    }
    for($i=0; $i<$mid; $i++){
        $colOne = $listing[$i];
        $colTwo = $listing[$i + $mid];//line 19
    }
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $colOne;//line 23
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $colTwo;
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</table>";
    //echo $data;*/
    //printf("%s (%s)\n",$roadID, $roadName, $reportingMark);
    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();
```

Comment: What is the goal? Why not do everything in the `while` loop?

Comment: The goal is to have to columns of data from the database. The example I used had the while loop end before the for loop began.

Answer (score 1):

You need to output your table rows as you loop over the data. Note that since each row is an array, you need to `implode` the row to output it as a string. In the code below I've assumed you want separate columns for each value in the row. You can use [`fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all) to avoid the loop over `fetch_row`. Also you need to take account of the fact that you may have an odd number of rows; in that case you need to supply default data for the second column in the last row. I've done this using [`array_fill`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill) to create an array of blank data. Combining all of this, replace the code after `$result = $stmt->get_result();` with this:

```
$listing = $result->fetch_all();
$mid = ceil(count($listing) / 2);
echo "<table>\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $mid; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . implode('</td><td>', $listing[$i]) . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . implode('</td><td>', $listing[$i+$mid] ?? array_fill(0, count($listing[0]), '')) . '</td>';
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ehJnP) (with random sample data) on 3v4l.org